# How to delete a large number of rows from a .CSV file?

Tags: r, csv

I'm new to R and Rstudio, so this may seem kinda odd.

I'm currently trying to eliminate some rows from a very big (roughly 400.000 rows) .CSV file, but I face some problems.

[image: Example of the Table(.CSV file)]

Here is the output I want (In this example, we deleted the row 6:
[image: Here is the output i want (In this example, we deleted the row 6]

1- When I execute:

```
tablename <- tablename[c(-row1, -row2), ]
```

for, let's say 7 rows, it works just fine for the first time I execute it. Then, if I execute the same syntax for another row that I want to delete. For example:

```
tablename <- tablename[c(-row3, -row4), ]" )
```

it seems that it dont delete the rows that I specified.

2- Because of the problem described above, I tried to create a 'super' syntax that has all the rows I want to delete. For example:

```
tablename <- tablename[c(-row1, -row2, ..., -row299, -row300), ]
```

The thing with this, is that it appears to do nothing (again). It just appears a '+' in the console, instead of the ' > '.

The last option I have, is to delete all the unwanted rows in the .CSV file with the Search Keyword option in WordPad, but it is not viable, as long as it would take me like 9 hours.

Answer (score 1):

As per your further discussion of your intentions (found in the comments in Nick Knauer's response) copied here:

> I'm going to give some intel about the project and why i do this.
>   Consider the column 'Code'. Column code specifies uniquely a Person (
>   it can be more than 1 row for the same person. In that case, the Code
>   will be the same) Consider, another column 'Class'. Class specifies a
>   social class of a person. I used an SQL command to see if the same
>   Person have diferent Social class along the file. What i noticed is
>   that the results have several Social Classes for the same Person. The
>   sintax i tried to write above are to delete the rows that have
>   diferent SocialClasse per Person.

Aha! Just tell your machine to make these judgements *AND* have it filter them out accordingly. It is really good at it!

First join that class table up to the employee dataframe with a `left_join`.
Then with a `group_by(code) %>% mutate(cnt_class = n_distinct(class))` you can reveal which are your dupes of class by code. Then with a `filter` you can most easily deal accordingly with your dupes.

If you would like more precise help, please post up a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) tl:dr - use `dput` to make a dataframe I can copy and paste into my rstudio and tinker with (never possible with a picture of the data).

For more info to help you leap up the learning curve, please see here for the simple menu/breakdown of other quick and easy `dplyr` data wrangling options - https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf

Answer (score 0):

To delete a row in R, you can do it this way:

```
employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
startdate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14'))
employ.data <- data.frame(employee, salary, startdate)

newdf<-employ.data[-c(1,2),]
```

That is for specific rows, if you want to do it for a range of rows, you can do it this way: (This will delete all the rows.)

```
newdf<-employ.data[-c(1:3),]
```

Comment: Perhaps i didn't explain myself very well; I'm sorry for it.
I can't use the "newdf<-employ.data[-c(1:3),]", because the rows aren't together in a specified range. 

They are just disorganized and pretty much scattered along the file.

Comment: Have you tried eliminating with the supersyntax for the newdf variable? So instead of saying "row1" you just write 1 and "row2" would be 2. You would be taking the indices of the rows rather than the row names

Comment: For example: TableName <- TableName[-c(1,2,...), ]?

I did tried. And unfortunately, the result is the same.

Comment: Can you revise the question with an original dataset and what you want the final output to look like? Doesn't have to be your actual dataset, just a template to base it off of

Comment: Already uploaded two examples. I couldn't upload a 3rd photo, so here is the link for the 'Super Sintax' example: http://i.imgur.com/Hz2T7Mf.png

Comment: is there a pattern or reason you are deleting those rows? It could be easier to delete rows by the pattern/reason rather than each one individually

Comment: I'm going to give some intel about the project and why i do this. Consider the column 'Code'. Column code specifies uniquely a Person ( it can be more than 1 row for the same person. In that case, the Code will be the same) 

Consider, another column 'Class'. Class specifies a social class of a person.

I used an SQL command to see if the same Person have diferent Social class along the file.

What i noticed is that the results have several Social Classes for the same Person.

The sintax i tried to write above are to delete the rows that have diferent SocialClasse per Person.